# what type of this in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

i revice my friend's script,

i got this line in oracle query :

```
select name, contact.utils.occupation_abbr(occupation)
from contact.staff
```

and i got :
*"CONTACT"."UTILS"."OCCUPATION_ABBR": invalid identifier*

this machine is not the original machine,
i think i miss copy something from the original machine.
I see in trigger or function list on the original machine and i don't find this there.

Any suggestion what i left?

== A BIT TRICKY ==

i get the function from packages body,
then i run the query and make it as function and it now become function :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a PL/SQL package.

The package name is `UTILS` and the function that is called is named `OCCUPATION_ABBR`

You need to copy the whole package from the other system, only the function is not enough.

The package can be found in the schema (user) `CONTACTS`

Comment: do you have a time to explained how to copy the packages?

Comment: Most SQL (GUI) clients have some way to display the source code of a package. Copy the SQL and run it in the target database.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a [user defined function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions231.htm). You'll need to source it from the original machine.

Comment: where i find that function? i don't see in function list anything contained *utils* or *occupation_abbr*